# Odd Django Problem

Tags: django

In my views I want to pass in an error condition.

```
def something(request):
    name = request.GET.get('name')
    if name is None:
        return render_to_response('myapp.html', {'invalid': 'true'})
```

Then in my template I want to display different things depending on this.

So I do:

```
{% if invalid %}
INVALID
{% else %}
ALL OK
{% endif %}
```

However, the output is:

INVALID

ALL OK

It shows both things - can anyone suggest any reason. Probably somethingstupid I did. But driving me mad.

Comment: As @pleasedontbelong suggested in his answer, do change your context to `{'invalid': True}`. Nonetheless both the values shouldn't get printed even with your existing code. Can you post the rest of the contents of the template?

Answer (score 2):

```
{'invalid': True}
```

maybe it's because of that..

Comment: Yes — because the string "false" actually evaluates to "true" (ie, `bool("false") == True`).